# How do I apply a startwith filter for LoadOptions in Devextreme?

Tags: typescript, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I'm trying to apply a filter for the TEST column to make it 'startwith' only 'DC'.

```
       load: (options) => {
      options.filter = ["startsWith", "TEST", "DC"];

      return this.Api.DebtorsApi.GetTestAPICall(
        options
      ).toPromise();
    },
```

My issue is that I get an error message:
System.ArgumentException: 'startsWith' is not a member of type 'ApiClass (Parameter 'propertyOrFieldName')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the wrong order.

```
  options.filter = ["TEST", "startsWith","DC"];
```